# Channel encoded data

Tags: correlation, channel

If a reciever recieves a stream of chips if channel-encoded data

-1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1

The recievers channel code is

-1 -1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 +1

How many bits of binary data are represented by the received set of chips?

My answer is 2

What binary data for this receiver is encoded in the set of received chips

I multiplied each chip in the stream of chips recieved by the users channel code in order

So for the first set I got

(-1 * -1) + (-1 *-1) +(1*1) + (1*1) + (-1*-1) + (-1 *-1) + (1*1) +(1*1)

which got me 8 so i scaled this down by 8 to get 1.

I repeated this set and got 0 for the 2nd set and got 0

So my answer is 1,0

Is this correct or have I got it wrong?